# How to configure Cloudflare Universal SSL or Let's Encrypt on Godaddy domain with no web host?

Tags: angular, heroku, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I've an angular app, which I've deployed on Heroku.
Also, I've a personal domain name bought from GoDaddy.

So my xxxx.mydomain.com currently displays xxxx.heroku.com (free dyno)

xxxx.heroku.com is already secure with "https" but my newly purchased domain is "http".
I want to use Cloudflare's Universal SSL or Let's Encrypt SSL to secure my xxxx.mydomain.com. is it possible?

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can create an Free SSL from let's encrypt and add certificate along with private key in heroku settings.

Even you can use https://www.sslforfree.com to generate the free SSL which is using let's encrypt (in background) to generate SSL.

Comment: before adding SSL you need to update your dyno to hobby or standard as heroku doesnot allow SSL on free dyno.

Additionally, when you upgrade your dyno heroku allow ACM to add SSL to your website but it doesnot support wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I see almost all answers suggesting the use of a third-party website be it zerossl or any other one to make letsencrypt SSL. Which is entirely unnecessary.
If you have a Linux based machine like ubuntu or mac os machine you can do it without depending on any third party website, very easily. Here is the step summary

1. Install certbot (On your local machine mac or pc)
2. Create certificate on manual mode using `sudo certbot certonly --manual`
3. verify domain by uploading text file in .welknown/.acmechallenge
4. Once generated open your certificate, private key and chain using vi
5. Now copy-paste those in the relevant section in GoDaddy

If you need step by steps instructions then you can [visit my post](http://www.amarendrasingh.com/tutorial/letsecrypt-certificate-on-godaddy-hosting-with-certbot/)